# Java: Finding multiple delimiters

Tags: java, time, delimiter

I'm trying to separate the hours, minutes, seconds, and milliseconds from an inputed time. Right now I have

```
public MillisTime(String str)
throws IllegalArgumentException {
    // Initialize values so that missing fields default to 0.
    int hours = 0, minutes = 0, seconds = 0, millis = 0;

    // Use Scanner class to parse the time string.
    // Catch InputMismatchException and rethrow IllegalArgumentException.
    Scanner scn = new Scanner(str);

    scn.useDelimiter(":");
    try {
        if (scn.hasNext()) hours = scn.nextInt();
        if (scn.hasNext()) minutes = scn.nextInt();
        if (scn.hasNext()) seconds = scn.nextInt();

        scn.useDelimiter(".");
        if (scn.hasNext()) millis = scn.nextInt();
    }
    catch (InputMismatchException ex) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                                           "String Input Mismatch Exception: " + str);
    }
    scn.close();
    this.setAllFields(hours, minutes, seconds, millis);
}
```

The input it is receiving is `"16:5:7.009"` and results in a `String Input Mismatch Exception`. If I take out the lines that look for the period and millis, and input something like `3:45` it works. How do I make this work to find `:` and `.`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception occurs because with a delimiter of ":", the subcomponents are `{16, 5, 7.009}`.  7.009 is not an integer so when you call `scanner.nextInt()` for the third time you get the exception.

Keep in mind that the delimiter scanner uses can be a regEx pattern, so it's possible for the delimiter to be `. OR :` at the same time:

```
scanner.useDelimiter(Pattern.compile("[\\.:]");
```

Comment: I get what you're saying, but when I compile, javac can't find the symbol for `Pattern`. Is this something I need to import?

Comment: You really need to learn to read the documentation. The Java API is documented with javadoc, and the documentation is available freely online. Look at http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#useDelimiter%28java.util.regex.Pattern%29, and you'll discover that Pattern is a class of the java.util.regex package. Since it's not in java.lang, you have to import it.

Comment: Nevermind! I just had to do `scn.useDelimiter("[:.]")` Thanks for leading me in the right direction :D

Answer (score 1):

Why you need to use Scanner, since the input is a String?

I suggest you use http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String) to separate the string from the delimiters.

Or, for a more elegant solution, use http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Here is an example using regular expressions for verify and splitting the string to extract the numbers (just to use two methods):

```
public class MillisTime {
    public MillisTime(String str)
    throws IllegalArgumentException {
        // Initialize values so that missing fields default to 0.
        int hours = 0, minutes = 0, seconds = 0, millis = 0;

        if(!str.matches("[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2}\\.[0-9]*")) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("String must in the pattern: ##:##:##.###(...)");
        }

        String[] splitted = str.split(":");
        if(splitted.length != 3) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("String Input Mismatch Exception: " + str);                
        }
        hours = Integer.parseInt(splitted[0]);
        minutes = Integer.parseInt(splitted[1]);
        String[] secondsAndMillis = splitted[2].split("[.]");
        seconds = Integer.parseInt(secondsAndMillis[0]);
        millis = Integer.parseInt(secondsAndMillis[1]);
        this.setAllFields(hours, minutes, seconds, millis);
    }

    private void setAllFields(int hours, int minutes, int seconds, int millis) {

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MillisTime("12:13:14.123");
    }
}
```